# Nginx proxy server with docker-compose not working with SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker-compose, https, nginx-config

I've been scratching my head trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a project running on a DigitalOcean droplet - it has 3 containers: an Nginx server and a frontend and api server. It was all working fine, but I've now tried to add an SSL cert to the Nginx server and the browser just gives back 'this site can't be reached'.

My docker-compose is as follows:

```
services:
  clarbeast-frontend: 
    container_name: clarbeast-frontend
    build: 
      context: ./frontend 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: clarbeast-frontend

  clarbeast-api:
    container_name: clarbeast-api
    build: 
      context: ./api 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: clarbeast-api
      
  clarbeast-nginx:
    container_name: clarbeast-nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: clarbeast-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - clarbeast-frontend
      - clarbeast-api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /root/nginx_bundle_5a52b057ab94.crt:/root/nginx_bundle_5a52b057ab94.crt
      - /root/example.com.key:/root/example.com.key
```

and my nginx.conf is as follows:

```
events {}

http {
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /root/nginx_bundle_5a52b057ab94.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/example.com.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://clarbeast-frontend:3000;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://clarbeast-api:9874;
        }
    }
}
```

my docker container for nginx is up and running fine according to the logs - when I've had the path to the certs wrong, it's complained. Can anyone see what the issue might be?

I've tried double checking all the paths

Answer (score 0):

I got it working - there were a few issues I had to address.

I wasn't exposing port 443 - so I needed to change the docker-compose to

```
ports:
      - "80:80"
```

I also needed to add `proxy_ssl_server_name on` to the `location` blocks for the frontend and api in the nginx.conf.